# Issues with Fedora 20 and bumblebee

Tags: graphics, nvidia, selinux, display, gpu

I'm experiencing several issues trying to use my Fedora 20 laptop NVIDIA Optimus technology.

My system:

```
ASUS N53S 
Fedora 20 x86-64
3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64 Kernel
Intel Core i7-2670QM
NVIDIA Geforce 630M
```

I installed Fedora 20 only yesterday, and immediately updated all the packages using yum. My laptop uses the NVIDIA Optimus technology, which cannot be disabled via BIOS.

I've previously used Fedora 16 and followed this guide:

http://duxyng.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/finally-working-nvidia-optimus-on-fedora/

to get bumblebee working. The guide worked flawlessly and I was successfully able to do CUDA development on my laptop with no issues at all.

For my Fedora 20 installation, the dyxyng guide did not work. With that guide, I was able to start up the bumblebee daemon, but GNOME wouldn't load up when I reboot.

I then used this official guide:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee

Bumblebee almost seems to work using these instructions. The discrete graphics is disabled, and can be enabled to run CUDA applications. I've managed to install CUDA 5.5 and was able to compile all the sample, including those using the driver api (cuda.so in /usr/lib65/nvidia-bumblebee). However, when I run any kind of graphical application, such as glxgears or an nbody (which uses CUDA) simulation (from the SDK), SELinux goes nuts and starts throwing up dozens of warnings:
[image: SELinux alerts on CUDA nbody]

Also, my laptop's screen won't turn on after waking the computer from suspension. Besides that, Fedora is using basic graphics when booting, It's possible this issue is unrelated to bumblebee, since my Fedora 16 install seemed boot fine and the screen was able to turn on after waking from suspension.

---

**EDIT**
I should mention that certain applications won't run under the bumblebee daemon. For example, the NVIDIA Visual Profiler will not start up when ran with optirun, i.e. `optirun nvvp`, but will run when executed normally by simply running the `nvvp` command.

Comment: There seems to be a big issue somewhere as I experience exactly the same. It seems to be related to kernel 3.12 & bumblebee. I also have a lot of issues with the gnome-shell. I will open a bug report on bugzilla and add the bug id as soon as this is done.

Comment: Done. See bug id: [#1049801](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1049801)